# Spatial autocorrelation in residuals of spaMM model after controlling for it

Tags: r, model, spatial, autocorrelation, assumption

I am trying to control for spatial variation which I suspect to be strong in my dataset. I am comparing a linear model from lme4 with 3 explanatory variables - 1 continuous fixed effect, 1 discrete fixed effect, and 1 random grouping effect - against a model fitted with the spaMM package to control for spatial autocorrelation based on the information in this blog post: https://datascienceplus.com/spatial-regression-in-r-part-1-spamm-vs-glmmtmb/. My response variable appears fairly normally distributed/maybe slightly right-skewed.

```
mod1<-lmer(Y ~ X + Species + (1|Area), data=data)
mod2<-fitme(Y ~ X + Species + (1|Area) + Matern(1|X+Y), data=data, family="gaussian")
```

I am testing the residuals for spatial autocorrelation using DHARMa:

```
sims<-simulateResiduals(mod1)
testSpatialAutocorrelation(sims, data$Long, data$Lat, plot=TRUE)
```

There is of course very highly significant spatial autocorrelation in the non-spatial model, but there still is nearly as much autocorrelation that is also very highly significant in the spatial model - isn't this supposed to have reduced to 0/non-significant?
The assumption plots from DHARMa (plot(mod2)) have no significant issues and suggest the models fit well, so why have I still got so much autocorrelation if I've controlled for it? Or have I controlled for it incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `spaMM` or `DHARMa`, but maybe consider using an off-the-shelf measure for spatial auto-correlation like Moran's I (I think the `ape` package has a function for it, but its not too hard to code from scratch).  At least then you'll be able to gauge if spatial autocorrelation is indeed present.

Comment: Also, for spatial models, note that "model fit" and "shrinkage" (spatial smoothing/regression to the mean) are competing goals.  Model fit is probably not the most important quantity to check. As a case in point, imagine if your model returned the observed values (so residuals = 0, and shrinkage = 0).  Would you be happy with that model?  Some amount of shrinkage will increase residuals (and lower model fit) - this is desireable.

Comment: Just a warning that this depends very delicately on the assumptions that are being made when simulating. Have you tried this with a test data set (or data that are themselves simulated)?

Comment: @BenBolker The residuals should always be assumed to be uncorrelated, no?  If not, then the model is failing to explain the variation in the data.

Comment: I'm trying to distinguish between (1) the software is not doing what we think it does/should do and (2) the model is not capturing the patterns in the data correctly. I was suggesting trying the approach on some data that were thought to be well-behaved/appropriately modeled by the proposed model (e.g., no spatial trends, no anisotropy/nonstationarity, etc.), therefore either a standard example that's known to work well or simulated "data"

Comment: thanks both, will try both approaches on simulated data. Using the actual model residuals and calculating Moran's I via ape package rather than DHARMa's simulation does improve the situation - non-spatial models had +ve SAC (~0.2) p<0.001, but spatial models have -ve SAC i.e. not clustered but not random either p<0.01. That's when using species as fixed effect - if I run a model for each species separately it does become non-significant, but had wanted to run as effect to preserve sample sizes